# How are Access Tokens used in CI such as Jenkins or CAKE build?

Tags: curl, artifactory

I know this is a pretty vague question but after reading the documentation here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens#AccessTokens-CreateTokens

A few things don't make sense. I can't tell how the token is used once it's created.  Using curl I issued the POST request to generate the token with and without the refreshable element.  I get a large bearer token but I'm puzzled after this.  I'm unable to use the username and token to perform any actions against the API which kind of makes sense as you would want to use an API token. So aside from Cross Site Authentication how is this bearer token actually used?

Do you use it as OAUTH credentials for a CI plugin? Did I miss something trying to use it as authentication for the API?

I'm looking for help from someone that's had success using this new feature and what they're using it for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the question we will make sure to update the relevant page.

I'm with JFrog BTW (:

There are a few options to authenticate using an access token.
1. it can be used instead of a password for basic authentication, this is relevant when using different clients which only support basic authentication.
You just need to make sure the user matches the username provide when generating the token using `-d "username=<USERNAME>"`https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens#AccessTokens-CreateTokens

```
curl -u<USERNAME>:<TOKEN> http://ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/system/ping
```

2. it can used as a bearer token as well in the authorization header

```
curl -H"Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" http://ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/system/ping
```

Specifically with CI servers tokens are useful for authenticating instead of credentials since, as you mentioned, the user doesn't have to exist in Artifactory if the group provided in `-d "member-of-groups:<GROUP>"` is configured in that instance so you don't need to manage a lot of bot users for your agents.
Also, when creating access tokens you can control their expiry, and like an API key it's revokable if set to non-expireable or refreshable.

In the near future we will introduce additional capabilities to use access tokens with JFrog CLI and our CI plugins.

Hope this help (:

Comment: Thanks for that. The documentation had me a little confused. I did manage to get it to work, had some permission issues with the group's permissions